# For each loop takes all elements of array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a issue here and I am not quite sure what is wrong. I make a query where I get Business categories which is serialized (categories), then for each of them I try to unserialize, but as result I get only the unserialized categories of the first item.

Here is my code:

```
$businesses= Businesses::where('visible' , 'yes')->where( 'delete' , 'no')->select('categories')->get();
        foreach ($businesses as $key => $business) {

            $categories = unserialize($business->categories);

            return view('test',['categories'=>$categories]);
        }
```

Comment: you are just returning on the first iteration. I am not able to post the code here. may be,I will post an answer

Comment: 1. You're overwriting `$categories` in each iteration instead of adding to it, 2. you're returning with the loop which terminates the execution. You might want to read up on PHP basics first before diving into a real app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this helps you,

```
$businesses= Businesses::where('visible' , 'yes')->where( 'delete' , 'no')->select('categories')->get();
$categories = array();
foreach($businesses as $key => $business) {
   $categories[] = unserialize($business->categories);
}
return view('test',['categories'=>$categories]);
```

**Issue:** you are returning the categories at the first iteration in foreach loop.
**Suggestion:** you can make an associative array in the foreach loop & return to view after the loop. Then in view, you can make use of the categories